# How to load a table view when coming to back with out selection index

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am using navigation controller and have table views inside views.
when i select any cell it it will navigate to another view. so,from there if i click back button it come sto previous view.But,it showing the cell which is selected previously. I dnt want this .it should not show which cell we selected previously.
Could any one help me how to get this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the apple docs : When the user selects a cell, you should respond by deselecting the previously selected cell (by calling the deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated: method) as well as by performing any appropriate action, such as displaying a detail view.

For more info see http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageSelections/ManageSelections.html